# How to insert an element value - using jQuery - into an alert box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, copy, alert

I am trying to add the Strong element to the alert box in this scenario. However it is returning "undefined".

Can someone let me know where I have gone wrong with my syntax here. Thanks

```js
$('.copyURL').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let ele = $(this).parent().siblings(':first-child').children();
  let label = $(this).parent().parent().siblings(':first-child').children();
  ele[0].select();
  ele[0].setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(ele[0].value);
  alert(label[0].value + "\r\n" + "\r\n" +
    "Copied: " + ele[0].value + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + "Use this link for your WEB site");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
      <strong>Copy This Strong Label Into Alert</strong>
  </label>
  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="columns small-7">
      <input type="text" value="<#servername>/<#Database_Name>/<#business_business>/gift" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-2">
      <a class="button full-width" href="./<#business_business>/gift" target="_blank">View</a>
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-3">
      <a class="button full-width secondary copyURL"><i class="far fa-clone"></i> Copy URL</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get the text from the `strong` element, not `value`:

```js
$('.copyURL').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let ele = $(this).parent().siblings(':first-child').children();
  let label = $(this).parent().parent().siblings(':first-child').children();
  ele[0].select();
  ele[0].setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(ele[0].value);
  alert(label[0].textContent + "\r\n" + "\r\n" +
    "Copied: " + ele[0].value + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + "Use this link for your WEB site");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
      <strong>Copy This Strong Label Into Alert</strong>
  </label>
  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="columns small-7">
      <input type="text" value="<#servername>/<#Database_Name>/<#business_business>/gift" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-2">
      <a class="button full-width" href="./<#business_business>/gift" target="_blank">View</a>
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-3">
      <a class="button full-width secondary copyURL"><i class="far fa-clone"></i> Copy URL</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, still learning about the right syntax - this works thankyou for your input!